# How to login into windows when password has national character and keyboard is set to US

Tags: windows, passwords, keyboard-layout, language

I have weird situation. My friend uses password with polish characters to log in into Windows. However while he was logged in he changed keyboard layout to US. Now when he tries to use "ł" character while entering password nothing happens.

How can I change keyboard layout to Polish without logging into Admin account?

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: It's Windows XP

Comment: I assume the 'alt' codes do not work on the login screen?

Comment: Michael Kaplan covered this [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2011/06/03/10171014.aspx)

Comment: I like the issue!

Comment: Apparently on Windows you have to enable the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Input Method\EnableHexNumpad` with a string value of "1" to enable hex code character input.  How lovely!  Apparently this is enabled by default in Mac OS.

Comment: @kinokijuf Good information, but what if you can't RDP into the machine?

Comment: Just tried alt+0322 on Windows 7 and it worked (with numpad)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If it is windows 7, then you should have a button on the lower left of the screen.
  (Actually two buttons. One to shut down without logging in and one to change the locale).
- Alternatively you could log in with another account and change the setting in the registry.
- Or you could boot from a live CD and set the password to nothing. There are a many tools to do this. [This](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) is one of them.

Edit: Just saw the new comment stating that it was XP.
The second and third options should still work.

Comment: On my Windows 7 the only options available on the lower left of the screen are the ease of use options.  The ease of use options have an on-screen keyboard option, but the "OSK" didn't have an option to enter Unicode characters.

Comment: Thanks... In the end We had to reset the password. ** Warring ** When password is reset You may loose access to encrypted folders.

Answer (score 1):

Log on as another user, then use Runas to run the users control panel as yourself and change your password.

Comment: This works as long as there's more then one account. In my friend case he has just one account ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you have RDP enabled, you could remote into your system and then change password.

Answer (score -1):

A workaround:
Use some linux live CD to remove Windows password.

Here is how:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14369/change-or-reset-windows-password-from-a-ubuntu-live-cd/

Comment: -1 this could cause further issues (like loss of private keys)

Comment: Still better than being locked out of your own PC..

Comment: Not necessarily. There could be valuable data encrypted with EFS.