# changing language to inter log in password windows-7

Tags: windows-7

I have a password to log into windows-7, but my keyboard doesn't change to my language i.e.Farsi by pressing alt+shift(Right) to enter my password. What can I do now?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I really have a problem with my pass and cant inter my system. Is there any way to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a button on the lower left of the login screen. (Actually two buttons. One to shut down without logging in and one to change the locale)
That will allow you to change keyboard layout.

Have a look at this: [How to login into windows when password has national character and keyboard is set to US](https://superuser.com/questions/464858/how-to-login-into-windows-when-password-has-national-character-and-keyboard-is-s/464872#comment546504_464872)